# How can I get 5 random questions from a class questions in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and created a quiz app. The app is working and displaying all 6 questions. I want to get 5 random questions from the class questions .I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get by shuffling the list and then accessing the 5 items from it like below

```
var randomQuestions = (questions..shuffle()).sublist(0,5);
```

check out this [exmaple](https://dartpad.dev/?id=22aa3079cd77488da3978116ea9872b2)

Comment: are you getting any problem?

Comment: No, Your suggestion worked out. Thank you.